# Adding text to a CGContext with Swift

Tags: swift, macos, core-graphics, cgcontext

I am using Swift 3 / Xcode 8 on macOS.

I override `draw` in an NSView and, using the current context, I am able to draw simple shapes (see code):

class sample: NSImageView {

```
override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    super.draw(dirtyRect)
    let context = NSGraphicsContext.current()?.cgContext;
    let length = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
    let p1 = CGPoint(x: 200, y: 200)
    let shape = "square"


    context!.beginPath()
    context!.move(to: p1)

    if shape == "line" {
        let pointEnd = CGPoint(x: p1.x + length.x, y: p1.y + length.y)
        context!.addLine(to: pointEnd)
    } else if shape == "square" {
        let p2 = CGPoint(x: p1.x + length.x, y: p1.y)
        let p3 = CGPoint(x: p1.x + length.x, y: p1.y + length.y)
        let p4 = CGPoint(x: p1.x, y: p1.y + length.y)
        context!.addLine(to: p2)
        context!.addLine(to: p3)
        context!.addLine(to: p4)
        context!.addLine(to: p1)
    }

    context!.setStrokeColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1.0)
    context!.setFillColor(red: 0, green: 1, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
    context!.setLineWidth(2.0)
    context!.strokePath()

    let textColor = NSColor(calibratedRed: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1.0)
    let textColorB = NSColor(calibratedRed: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0.0)
    let rect = CGRect(x: 200, y: 200, width: 30, height: 130)
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.alignment = .center
    let attr = [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: textColor, NSBackgroundColorAttributeName: textColorB, NSFontAttributeName:NSFont.init(name: "HelveticaNeue-Thin", size: 14)]

    let q: NSString = "hello, world"
    let center = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    q.draw(at: center, withAttributes: attr)                                                                 
}
```

**The above is corrected to show the entire method.**

**This works as expected except for the text draw. Two draws I tried are shown in the last 2 lines. The first is as suggested below and it crashes (see message in comment for that line). The second is close but it demands an NSDrawingContext, not a CGContext.**

I would also like to draw some text (say right beneath the line). I have done a LOT of searching and have found nothing that works. CGContexts seems to have methods related to drawing text but none seem to actually draw it. To be clear, I found nothing that would compile, much less run.

Note: I am new to macOS development (done some iOS though). So I could be missing something very obvious.

**The problem was in the color assignment in the attributes.
Edited with code that now works.**

Comment: "I found nothing that would compile" — please **show the code** if you are having trouble getting something to compile. We can't help you with code that isn't available. (Furthermore, "none seem to actually draw it" seems to imply that you did manage to run the code, yet saw nothing on screen.)

Comment: Check out these methods as well: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/Tasks/DrawingAttrStrings.html

Comment: And does your current drawing code really work without a `stroke`/`fill` call?

Comment: none able to draw it meant that there were methods like "setTextPosition" that suggested a connection but nothing to actually draw.

Comment: The code shown is missing the stroke. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way to draw text into current graphics context is with NSString's [`draw(at:withAttributes:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring/1533109-draw).

Example:

```
class MyView : NSView {
    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        let atts = [NSFontAttributeName:NSFont.init(name: "Georgia", size: 30)]
        ("Hello world" as NSString).draw(
             at: NSMakePoint(100,100), 
             withAttributes: atts)
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I did try that as I recall but I frankly don't remember how it did not work for me. Perhaps it was not possible to make it work with cgContext. So I will try it again and get back to you.

Comment: OK I tried it again. It fails with a "gives unrecognized selector sent to instance " error that I suspect is something ro do with not referencing the context. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: I really don't know what you mean by all that. Of course it works. I've edited my answer to show some sample code and the visible drawing in the running application.

Comment: Yes, it does work, even for me now. My problem was in my assignment of the text color as CGColor.white. When I replace that by:

Comment: How do I declare that this is the answer I wanted?